# Google's Speech Recognition API (recognize_google function in python) Usage Limits?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech-recognition-api

Can you give more information about Google's Speech Recognition API (recognize_google function in python) Usage Limits?

The website (https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/3.1.3/) shows

To obtain your API key, follow the steps on the API Keys page at the Chromium Developers site.
In the Google Developers Console, Google Speech Recognition is listed as "Speech API".
Note that the API quota is 50 requests per day, and there is currently no way to raise this limit.

However, it seems I can call the API more than 50 requests per day (without my API key).
Can you explain more about this information? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The limits are 1 min or 10mb per transaction

Request Limits

> The current API usage limits for Speech-to-Text are as follows:
>
> 900 requests per 60 seconds
>
> Processing per day: 480 hours of audio